# How to do a backup with .bat with windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup

I have a file .bat that do a backup but i want to do another file .bat that remove the oldest files. Someone can help me?

```
set dia=%DATE:~0,2%
echo %dia%
if exist f:\exist.txt goto OK
echo KKKKKKKKKK
pause
exit

:OK
md f:\backup
md f:\backup\%dia%
xcopy d:\dat\*.* f:\backup\%dia%\*.* /s /c /h /r /e /y /j
echo TODO OK
pause
```

Comment: I would recommend `robocopy` see from `cmd` `robocopy /?` as it can keep the files in sync without having to recreate files.

Comment: something like `robocopy "C:\source\" Z:\dest" /MIR /Z` If you really require more than one backup directory in order to revert to older backup, the please let me know and I can show you how. Typically you'll then only leave 3 or 4 dates of files.

Comment: To be clear, you're not new to this site, so must have taken the [tour], and read through [ask] and each of its included linked pages. So your question is clear that you want to create a `.bat` file which removes the oldest files from a directory or tree. What have you posted completely unrelated code for? and where is the code you have written to remove those files? This site is not a code request service, we cannot help you to fix a specified reproducible issue with your code, if you omit it from your question. **Your question, in its current state, is off topic on StackOverflow.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read carefully please! The script has a safeguard `echo` in the `rmdir` line. Do not remove this until you are 100% sure the script does what you want.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=.=" %%i in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do set result=%%i
set "mydate=%result:~0,8%"
robocopy "d:\dat" "f:\backup\%mydate%" /MIR /Z
for /f "skip=4 delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /o-d "f:\backup\"') do echo rmdir /S/Q "%%~fa"
pause
```

So the script will create a folder for each date `yyyymmmdd` each time you run it, if the folder already exists i.e you ran the backup twice in one day, it will simply update the files and not recreate any folders if they exist.

The second for loop you have to be carefull of. it will sort the folders by decending date, i.e the latest created folders will be listed first. So you will see here I have `skip=4` meaning it will skip the first 4 latest folders, and delete the rest. So if you want to keep two latest backups, then do `skip=2` etc.

to amend the date to `yyyymm` only, change to `set "mydate=%result:~0,6%"`. You get the idea.